# Unusual choice: Windows XP (x64) vs. Windows Server 2008 (x64)

Tags: windows-xp, 64-bit, windows-server-2008

I'm looking to install a x64 OS to take advantage of 6GB of RAM.

My options are Windows XP Pro and Windows Server 2008.

This box will not be used as a server, but I don't want to install the old OS either.

Any pro's / cons for either choice?

Any insights appreciated.

#### p.s.:

went with Server 2008 ... http://www.win2008workstation.com/wordpress/ helped a lot

Comment: What will you be using the computer for? I know you're not using as a server, but what programs do you want to run etc.

Comment: used for web development / personal use

Comment: recommendation ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 have same base as Vista.

But if you have only this options, I recommend Server 2008.

Because XP (x64) is very old and MS support has expired and haven't new updates.

UPDATE: You mentioned "web development" and for this is good Server, because have hyper-v for virtualization.

Comment: WinXP 64bit is still supported, and will continue to be for another 5 years. See here: http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=8599

Comment: @Richard: But only with "Extended Support Retired" (it's paid support) and last SP is SP2

Comment: XP 64-bit is horrible, unstable and has very bad support when it comes to drivers, antivirus software, etc. Definitely not recommended.

Comment: There are even sites dedicated to turning Windows Server 2008 into a workstaion OS: http://www.win2008workstation.com/wordpress/

Answer (score 7):

One of the biggest reasons to go with Windows 2008 Server is driver support. 3rd-party 64-bit drivers on XP are not very good and not getting better.

Another added benefit as a web developer, is the ability to use IIS7 as your development server. The web server in XP only supports one web root. This can be a pain when developing for web apps that must be installed at the root of a site.

Comment: +1 for mentioning IIS7 as it does not run on XP.  Very handy for us web guys.

Answer (score 3):

Windows XP x64 is built on top of an OS which is 8 years old; true that the x64 release was quite a way after.

Here are the system requirements for Windows XP x64 (via: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457053.aspx)

> Processor
> 733 MHz Intel Itanium
> 800 MHz Intel Itanium
>
> Memory
> 1 GB RAM
> 1 GB RAM

Conversely Windows Server 2008 is built on top of the same kernel as Vista and has things such as UAC (love it or hate it UAC *is* a step in the right direction) and a better CPU schedular. Win 2k8 was build in the era of multi-core processing, unlike XP.

For the record here are the Win 2k8 system requirements (via: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/system-requirements.aspx):

> Processor
> Minimum: 1 GHz (x86 processor) or 1.4 GHz (x64 processor)
>
> Memory
> Minimum: 512 MB RAM

My vote - Windown Server 2008.

Comment: Windows XP x64 uses the same kernel as Server 2003 - it even reports its version as 5.2.